# Mass dimension of Klein Jordan field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, klein-gordon-equation

I like to know about dimension of KG fields,
Wikipedia searches don't give me a satisfied  answer 
Can any one please help  me?

Comment: Klein  - Jordan  ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Elaborate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on dimension of space-time. Consider action of KG-field in $D$ dimensions,
$$S=\int d^Dx\left[-\frac{1}{2}\phi(\partial^2+m^2)\phi\right].$$
In QFT, this action usually appears as $\exp(-S[\phi])$, so $S$ should be dimensionless. Therefore, for $D$-dimensional space-time, dimensions of field $\phi$ is
$$[\phi]=\frac{D}{2}-1.$$
It is measured in $M$ units, where $M$ is mass units, whereas $[x]=M^{-1}$. Let us check this: 
$$[\text{vol}]+[\phi]+[\phi]+2=-D+2\cdot(D/2-1)+2=0,$$
where $[\text{vol}]$ means measure $d^Dx$